# unit of argument -s for calibration.cpp

Tags: opencv

I'm now reading the code of 
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/samples/cpp/calibration.cpp
according to the code, it has an argument called -s  which the default value is 1.

My question is, what is the unit of this parameter ? mm, cm, or meter ?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is your physical unit of reference. If you know that a square of oyur calibration pattern has sides of 10 cm and pass `-s 10`, then it will be expressed in cenntimeters, etc.

This is why the default value is one: everything geets expressed with respect to the suqare side length.